# TimeField and DurationField int error

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.10

I have run into this error when running python manage.py migrate when using DurationField and TimeField both give me a:

```
return int(round(value.total_seconds() * 1000000))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

I have seen this error on this site but only for a Django 1.8. Currently, I am using Django 1.10.
I have tried these suggesions :

```
DurationField(default=timedelta()), 
DurationField(), 
DurationField(default=timedelta()), 
DurationField(default=int(timedelta(minutes=20).total_seconds())).
```

My model currently looks like:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lunchnumber = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES,null=True, blank=True)
    breaktime = models.DurationField(default=timedelta(minutes=45))

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        if isinstance(value, datetime.timedelta):
            return value
        try:
            parsed = parse_duration(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if parsed is not None:
                return parsed
```

Addressing Prakhar Trivedi's question:
I do not know what value is not working well. I was under the assumption it was the default value that django is trying populate that database table with. I am under this impression because of 
    .......in get_db_prep_value
    return int(round(value.total_seconds() * 1000000))
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Addressing iklinac's Answer:

I went in and added the default=timedelta(minutes=45). I do have it imported from datetime But I feel I am missing something. I am very new at this and have not seen a to_python function. What am I missing I am still getting the same error?

Comment: What is **value** in **value.total_seconds()**. Which of the field is value of ur model??

Comment: ooh @PrakharTrivedi that's what I meant to ask, it seems i asked seomthing else :)

Comment: Hey Travis did you check out that you have timedelta imported in way I stated below in your models.py. Also regarding to_python function that is function behind Duration field no need to include it up. Regarding the last part of comment if datetime is still having problems you could use django time format stated below in comment section of parse_value

Comment: So you could set up default='timestring' of formats stated below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you are importing timedelta from datetime package :)

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

These two should work

```
DurationField(default=timedelta(minutes=20))
DurationField(default=timedelta())
```

to_python function of DurationField is following

```
    if value is None:
        return value
    if isinstance(value, datetime.timedelta):
        return value
    try:
        parsed = parse_duration(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        if parsed is not None:
            return parsed
```

If you are still having troubles with timedelta you could use one of these formats as stated in parse_duration code comments

```
def parse_duration(value):
    """Parses a duration string and returns a datetime.timedelta.

    The preferred format for durations in Django is '%d %H:%M:%S.%f'.

    Also supports ISO 8601 representation.
    """
    match = standard_duration_re.match(value)
    if not match:
        match = iso8601_duration_re.match(value)
    if match:
        kw = match.groupdict()
        if kw.get('microseconds'):
            kw['microseconds'] = kw['microseconds'].ljust(6, '0')
        kw = {k: float(v) for k, v in six.iteritems(kw) if v is not None}
        return datetime.timedelta(**kw)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have quite the same problem, and iklinac's Answer helped me.

Once I ran the python manage.py makemigrations and showing

```
You are trying to change the nullable field 'duration' on task to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
 3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

So I set a 0 to the DurationField cause of laziness...

after that the error keeps showing...

By seen this answer I found that when running "python manage.py migrate" it actually running a 000x_auto_xxxx.py in the folder named migrations. so I found that .py file which contained the field=models.DurationField(default=0)
and change it to the right way, and finally solve the problem.

Hope this may help